# Find Id of View in Child Activity

Tags: android

I have an issue , need your help , my question is : I have a multiple activity , so i have created one abstract class which hold the view . Now my question i am able to pass the view to the Base Activity but how to finds view id in Child Activity Class.

I Tried like this :

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());
   }

   public abstract int getLayoutResourceId();

}
My Activity Class:
    public class ServiceActivity extends BaseActivity {
        Button startSerice_btn, stopService_btn;
        MyService myService;

        @Override
        public int getLayoutResourceId() {
            return R.layout.service_xml;
        }

    }
```

Comment: get it before setContentView.

Comment: setcontentview is my parent activity class , i need the view id in service activity class , because if their is multiple activity and we write the whole activity view id in base activity then the app will crash

Comment: Red more about findViewById. It is getting id from view from which you set recently.

Comment: override onCreate in child ativity, call super, and then findById your views as usual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your views after the `super.onCreate()` call in the `ServiceActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Access them here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think you no need to set content view in BaseActivity like below :

```
public abstract class MyAppBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

> And you just extends Activity like below :

```
    // for MyCustomActivity1 
   public class MyCustomActivity1 extends MyAppBaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}


    // for MyCustomActivity2

     public class MyCustomActivity2 extends MyAppBaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using onCreate method in MyCustomActivity1  and MyCustomActivity2  then why you are making the abstract class and overriding the oncreate in that ? Abstract class is that where i can put the common behaviour and reuse that method anywhere in activity .

Comment: Yes you are right we can use some of common function like. a) On double time back pressed close activity 2) Some default click events etc . the concept of common activity no need to worry about common functions.

Comment: I have update my answer you can see i have add o View.OnClickListener and will get default override method in MyCustomActivity1 and MyCustomActivity2

Comment: My issue is , in every activity we use oncreate view , so it's better to define in the abstract class and let all my child activity extends base class activity , so i did in my code i have passed layout from the child to base class , now the issue arises here , every activity has it's own view and there view child id (suppose activity A contains two button means two button id ) similiary Activity B contains one textview , then we can't write their id(Activity A as well As Activity B) in base activity right,we have to find there id in the activity class itself .